# How to connect with SSH to RPi through hostapd hotspot?

Tags: ssh, hotspot

I have created a hotspot on my RPi with this [tutorial](http://elinux.org/RPI-Wireless-Hotspot).

This hotspot is working well, but now I want to control my RPI with SSH from computers connected to this hotspot.

When I try to connect, the connection fails (timeout).

When I type `ip add show` on my RPi, it shows that it has two IP addresses on `wlan0`:

- `192.168.42.1/24` - the static address I give to my RPi
- `169.254.10.181/16` - I don't know from where this address comes from!

So, how can I connect to my RPi with SSH from my computer through HostAPD hotspot?

Could this second IP address be the origin of my troubles with SSH connection?

Answer (score 1):

### The problem is Solved !

The origin was a conflit between two DNS servers : `isc-dhcp-server` & `udhcpd`

`Hostapd` working well, but after the connection the conflit between the two servers do not permise to attributing IP to clients. And so, to complete the connection.

The solution was to reinitialize the RPI and install only one of this two servers (`udhcpd` in my case)

Thank for your reply

Answer (score 0):

I can connect via SSH to my Hotspot no problem with Raspberry Pi 2 Model B.

Questions:

- Which Pi Model do you have?
- Which address did you assign to your hostapd hotspot?
- Can you connect to the hotspot from a different computer than the pi?

Also, the second IP Address (169.254.10.181/16) is an APIPA Address. Could you post the whole output of `ip addr show wlan0` ?

Sorry , don't have enough reputation yet to comment.